# Downloaded a Nextjs Website Template from the internet, Opened in Vs code but its not running when I "npm run dev" getting an error

Tags: npm-install, next.js13

I have downloaded a nextjs website template and i would like to edit it and run it locally but it's not running. Please see the attached screenshot    [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U934.jpg)

I ran 'npm install' after opening the downloaded file in vs code. I proceeded to run 'npm run dev' but got an error. I was expecting it to run locally like the live demo here https://startup-agency-classic.vercel.app/

Comment: I wouldn't run it out of OneDrive. NPM has a hard enough time getting things right on Windows machines. I would personally run it closer to the root of the machine. Will that fix your problem? No idea. But it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete node module folder and try again with your commands